# How to Create a Timeseries mixed and multi axis chart using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to create a mixed chart having months and days on the X axis.
suppose the dataset is like

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-28 | 4 |
| 2023-02-27 | 12 |
| 2023-02-25 | 9 |
| 2023-03-02 | 1 |
| 2023-03-10 | 4 |

Now I want to create a line chart for the date and a bar chart for the months the value for dates is given in the dataset but the value for the month is sum of all values of that month.

I want chart something like this[image]

May be we can create it using multiple x axis with different chart type. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

Comment: Have you tried to use 2 time scales, one for the bar dataset and another one for the line, with different time unit?

Comment: ok so I worked on data as an array that takes x-axis default as labels now I convert my data to json format for x and y values.